# The difference between GotFocus and GotKeyboardFocus

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

What is the difference(s) between `GotFocus` and `GotKeyboardFocus` -and similarly `LostFocus` and `LostKeyboardFocus`?

Sorry for the simple question, but, I googled it and read a lot of blog posts, but I'm still confused. It seems nobody knows exactly what is the difference ):

**UPDATE:**

My usage:

I am creating a custom control by extending `Control` class. Something like `ComboBox` but with some other effects. I'm trying to open and close a `Popup` by setting a property: `IsDropDownOpen` just like a `ComboBox` through the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events. I don't want to `Popup` get closed, when I `Alt+Tab`ed the windows, but get closed when I click on a `Button` for example or I go to a `TextBox`. I did:

```
private static void OnGotFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Handled)
        return;
    ((SearchBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private static void OnLostFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Handled)
        return;
    ((SearchBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The `GotFocus` works. But the `Lost` one didn't. If I do the `Lost` stuff in `LostKeyboardFocus` then when I `Alt+Tab` the windows, or `Window` goes to inactive, then the method get called, while I don't want. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) has an overview of focus, but I'll try to explain it here.

WPF has 2 concepts regarding focus. There is the physical keyboard focus, and there is logical focus. Only one element can have keyboard focus (and if the application isn't the active application, no element will have keyboard focus).

Multiple items can have logical focus. In fact, you can create new "focus scopes". As per MSDN:

> When keyboard focus leaves a focus scope, the focused element will lose keyboard focus but will retain logical focus.  When keyboard focus returns to the focus scope, the focused element will obtain keyboard focus. This allows for keyboard focus to be changed between multiple focus scopes but ensures that the focused element in the focus scope regains keyboard focus when focus returns to the focus scope.

You can define your own focus scope on an element (typically a `Panel`) by setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"`. The controls in WPF that are focus scopes by default are `Window`, `MenuItem`, `ToolBar`, and `ContextMenu`.

This makes sense if you think about having multiple `Window`s in your application. When you `Alt-Tab` between them, you expect your keyboard focus to return to the same place it was the last time the `Window` had focus. By keeping keyboard focus and logical focus separate, you can achieve this.

Comment: +1 thanks, good explanation. actually better than MSDNs'. Thanks a lot. I wait for more answers a while, and then -if no better one received- accepts yours.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to open a `Popup` (in a custom control inherited from `Control` class) by setting a `IsDropDownOpen` property. I set it to `true` in `GotFocus`, it works. I want to set it to `false`, in `LostFocus` event. But it doesn't work. I don't want to do it in `LostKeyboardFocus`, but in `LostFocus`. Any idea please?

Comment: I think you're going to need to create a new question with some code examples. I can't debug your scenario from that brief description.

Comment: @king.net: Did you end up creating a question about your particular problem? I *might* be having a related problem, and I'd like to read it and its answers.